# Como funciona los metodos de la clase Route en laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo esta ruta pero no logro entender la mayoria ya me pase a leer la documentación pero me quede con las dudas:

```
Route::namespace('Admin')
     ->prefix('admin')
     ->name('admin.')
     ->middleware(['auth', 'admin'])
     ->group(function () 
    {

      Route::get('lista-productos','productosController@index);

    });
```

Alguien podría explicarme de favor de como funciona el namespaesce, name, se lo agradeceria mucho. Lo demás como el prefix entiendo como funciona al igual que middleware pero ya no entiendo como implementarlo para que se puedan ser llamados

Answer (score 1):

El método `->name('.admin')` se utiliza como un factor de nombramiento común para la mayoría o todas las rutas que tengas y que apunten a `/admin`

Por ejemplo tienes este grupo de rutas:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'DemoController@index');

Route::post('/admin', 'DemoController@update');
```

Dentro de tus formularios tienes algo así:

```
action="{{ route('admin') }}"
```

Las dos rutas anteriores acceden a `/admin` sin embargo si en un futuro necesitas que ahora tu ruta sea: `/admin-enterprise` entonces después vas a tener que actualizar una por una para que apunten a la ruta nueva.

Por otro lado si a tus rutas las nombras así:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'DemoController@index')->name('admin');

Route::post('/admin', 'DemoController@update')->name('admin');
```

Aunque después las cambies a:

```
Route::get('/admin-enterprise', 'DemoController@index')->name('admin');

Route::post('/admin-enterprise', 'DemoController@update')->name('admin');
```

La URL dentro de tus formularios no necesita cambiar, sino que puedes seguir usando `admin` por que fue el nombre que les asignaste

La ruta en tus formularios seguiría siendo similar a esta

```
action="{{ route('admin') }}"
```

Comment: En esta parte <form action="url('/admin')"> no seria en lugar de url el route? {{route(/admin)}}  porque lo he estado trabajando asi lo explico y me decia que la ruta esta siendo indefinida algo asi

Comment: Como seria dentro de un group? lointente hacer pero me manda error no entiendo

Answer (score 1):

El método `namespace()` funciona muy similar a los namespaces en PHP (y en casi cualquier otro lenguaje), en el caso de los grupos de rutas, permite «obviar» una parte de la ruta del controlador, normalmente se obvia la parte de `App\Http\Controller`, pero en el caso puntual de la pregunta, estamos obviando `App\Http\Controller\Admin`.

En otras palabras, si no utilizaramos dicho método, la ruta tendría que ser llamada de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::get('lista-productos','Admin\productosController@index);
```

---

En cuanto a `name('admin.')`, no es más que un prefijo para los nombres que se le den a las rutas del grupo, aunque no se está aprovechando en el código de la pregunta. La ruta mostrada debería tener un nombre, aún si es la única, esto con fines de escalabilidad:

```
Route::get('lista-productos','productosController@index)->name('products.list');
```

De esta forma la ruta se referenciará desde cualquier parte de la aplicación de la   siguiente manera:

```
route('admin.products.list')
```